# I want to ask for permission to send a link to a group of students

Tags: email, grammar

> Dear professor,
>
> The following is an online writing resource that could help learner to
>   write the essay: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/ . May I know If
>   could I send it to the course? Thank you in advance.
>
> Regards,

I want to know if this email is well written. I am a teaching fellow and I should ask for permission before sending something.

Comment: I'm sorry, but asking for help with writing an email is off topic for this site and isn't allowed. http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: A clarification: we can't help with general feedback, or saying whether something is "well-written" - we've tried in the past, and it works poorly within the Q&A format. Asking *specific*, answerable questions about email-writing can be fine, within our on-topic boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

This is a request for proofreading, which doesn't really fit here on the writer's group.  We're looking for questions about and related to the writing process.

However...

Here's my edit to your email.  This is just one way to do it, and might not be the best way... There are a million ways to write something like this and it can depend on personal style and the relationship that you have with your professor.

Dear Professor,

I found a web link that might be helpful to the other students taking our course.  I'm wondering if it would be appropriate if I sent it out to them, or if you'd prefer that I do not.

For your reference, the link is: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/

Thanks,